# Polynomial solutions to $ax^4+bx^2+c^2 = y^2$, with $a,b,c$ as polynomials

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

While investigating a system involving "*equal sums of like powers*", an elliptic curve popped up,

$$9 (1 + 4 n^4)^2 + 30 (4 + n^2 - 24 n^4 + 4 n^6) x^2 + 5 (32 - 40 n^2 + 53 n^4) x^4 = y^2$$

Some easy rational points are,

$$x = (0,\; 1,\; n)$$

Using the tangent-chord method, from the last two, we get,

$$\; x = \frac{6 (1 + 4 n^4)  (17 + 12 n^2)}{151 - 49 n^2 + 144 n^4 + 144 n^6}$$
$$x = \frac{\; 6 (1 + 4 n^4)  (3n + 23 n^3)}{9 + 9 n^2 - 79 n^4 + 121 n^6}$$

**Question:** But are there rational points where the numerator and denominator are polynomials of degree less than 6, preferably only quadratics?

Comment: $(y + c)(y - c)=x^2(ax^2 + b)$ - Heavy simplification into this form might help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at a bunch of examples, it appears that your curve (which is isomorphic to an elliptic curve) has rank $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(n)$. Using this, one can find some other rational points of degree $\leq 6$, but not where the numerator or denominator is a quadratic. In particular, there are solutions when
$$
  x = \frac{12 n^{4} + 3}{12 n^{3} \pm 23n^{2} + 17n \pm 3}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. Substituting this into the system, I end up with another curve $F(n) = z^2$ where $F(n)$ is of degree 7. Sigh. (I was hoping it would be at most only of degree 4 thus isomorphic to an elliptic curve. I will post the system tomorrow.)

Comment: This [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191932/) is the context to the curve above. Essentially, the curve is the discriminant of the _quartic_ condition in the MO post (with some variables specialized).

Comment: Given the form $ax^4+bx^2+c^2 = y^2$, can the point you found be expressed in terms of general $a,b,c,$ or is it specific only to this curve?

Comment: No - the points I found are specific to the coefficients $a$, $b$ and $c$ you specified in the question. I would guess that for a generic $a$, $b$ and $c$, the corresponding elliptic curve has rank $1$ over $\mathbb{Q}(a,b,c)$.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I'm using various approaches to solve Choudhry's system in the MO post, but I keep getting $F(n) = z^2$ where $F(n)$ has degree $>4$. Sigh.

Comment: Still no headway in Choudhry's system, but you may be interested in [this elliptic curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4642635/).